# Change of Coordinates matrix.

Tags: matrices, coordinate-systems

If Q is the change of coordinates matrix From some basis B to B', then Q inverse is the change of coordinates matrix from B' to B? Is this true?

I think/ know it is the, but don't know how to prove it

Comment: Absolutely true. The change of coordinates matrixs from $\mathcal B$ to $\mathcal B'$ is the matrix of the identity map  from the space with basis $\mathcal B'$ to the space with basis $\mathcal B$, and symmetrically. That's why the two matrices are the inverse of each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's true, and it is a consequence of linearity and the definion of inverse matrix. If you have a Basis $\{\mathbf{e}_i\}$ and a linear transformation $\mathbf{e'}_i=Q\mathbf{e}_i$ than : $\mathbf{e}_i=I\mathbf{e}_i=Q^{-1}Q\mathbf{e}_i=Q^{-1}\mathbf{e'}_i$, and since any vector $\mathbf{v}$ can be expressed as a linear combination $\mathbf{v}=\sum_i v_i\mathbf{e}_i$, the same hold for any vector.